# How to create queryextender control dynamically in the page

Tags: asp.net

I created two table and make regNo as reference using linq.How to add query extender control dynamically in page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through [QueryExtender Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryextender.aspx) for implementation of this control..

Create the object of this control class and add it to the page at the `Page_Init` event:

```
QueryExtender control = new QueryExtender ();
```

//Set it's properties and `Expressions` collection or filters etc
`Target Control` and other as you see in the typed implementation...

```
this.Page.Form1.Controls.Add(control);
```

Check this for implementation information
[Working with Query Extender control](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Working-with-Query-Extender-control.aspx)

Comment: i displayed the table in grid view dynamically using linq query. Now what sould be the targetId and datasource for that control.Also message says that control.Datasource is read only..thanks

Comment: use the linq datasoource id in the targetcontrol id...  check the last lines of article specified in the answer.. they will clear  your doubut about this...